# Why do I get such long runtime when using bitwise operation in a large loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am implementing some code for some machine learning algorithm. I came across a segment of code which had particular long runtime for unknown reason. So I decide to simplify the problem a bit an investigate why I am getting such long runtime.

The long runtime occurs when using the bitwise operation & for large loops compared to the > floating point comparison. When comparing the bitwise & operation with the > floating point comparison, & only performs marginally slower.

```
import numpy as np
import time

# Create toy dataset
x = 1.0
y = 2.0

xxx = np.array([
    [True, False, True],
    [True, False, False]
])


t0 = time.time()
z = x if x > y else y
t1 = time.time()

total = t1-t0
print('>', 'time:', total)


t0 = time.time()
zzz = xxx[0,:] & xxx[1,:]
t1 = time.time()

total = t1-t0
print('&', 'time:', total)
```

Output

```
> time: 9.202957153320312e-05
& time: 0.00010704994201660156
```

In my implementation I have used a list comprehension to loop over the variables in my algorithm. I have implemented a simplified version here.

```
import numpy as np
import time

# Create toy dataset
x = 1.0
y = 2.0

xxx = np.array([
    [True, False, True],
    [True, False, False]
])


iterations_list = np.array([1e3, 1e4, 1e5], dtype=int)
for iterations in iterations_list:
    print('=========')
    t0 = time.time()
    z = [x if x > y else y for _ in range(int(iterations))]
    t1 = time.time()

    total = t1-t0
    print('>','iterations:', iterations, 'time:', total)


    t0 = time.time()
    zzz = [xxx[0,:] & xxx[1,:] for _ in range(int(iterations))]
    t1 = time.time()

    total = t1-t0
    print('&','iterations:', iterations, 'time:', total)

    print('=========')
```

Output

```
=========
> iterations: 1000 time: 0.00013589859008789062
& iterations: 1000 time: 0.0023381710052490234
=========
=========
> iterations: 10000 time: 0.0014920234680175781
& iterations: 10000 time: 0.04303407669067383
=========
=========
> iterations: 100000 time: 0.011501789093017578
& iterations: 100000 time: 112.03882884979248
=========
```

Notice the significantly longer runtime for 100000 for the & operation. At first I thought this was a problem because of list comprehensions. So I thought I would try with for loops as well. But the problem still occurs.

```
import numpy as np
import time

x = 1.0
y = 2.0

xxx = np.array([
    [True, False, True],
    [True, False, False]
])


iterations_list = np.array([1e3, 1e4, 1e5], dtype=int)
for iterations in iterations_list:
    print('=========')

    t0 = time.time()
    z = list()
    for _ in range(int(iterations)):
        z.append(x if x > y else y)
    t1 = time.time()

    total = t1-t0
    print('>','iterations:', iterations, 'time:', total)


    t0 = time.time()
    zzz = list()
    for _ in range(int(iterations)):
        zzz.append(xxx[0,:] & xxx[1,:])
    t1 = time.time()

    total = t1-t0
    print('&','iterations:', iterations, 'time:', total)

    print('=========')
```

Output:

```
=========
> iterations: 1000 time: 0.0018820762634277344
& iterations: 1000 time: 0.1021728515625
=========
=========
> iterations: 10000 time: 0.0039157867431640625
& iterations: 10000 time: 0.03302407264709473
=========
=========
> iterations: 100000 time: 0.029590129852294922
& iterations: 100000 time: 103.38917803764343
=========
```

This result is quite strange. Since list comprehensions usually perform faster than a for loop because it does not require to call the append subroutine. The experimental results have sort have shown this for all the runtime except for the & operation for 100000 iterations, which seems to perform faster than the list comprehension.

Can anyone explain why there is such a large increase in runtime for using the & operation at 100000 iterations or more? Also what are the solutions to implement an algorithm similar to get a faster runtime?

## EDIT:

I have ran my experiment with the following packages

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_anaconda_depends         2019.03                  py37_0  
_ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf    0.1.0                    py37_0  
alabaster                 0.7.12                   py37_0  
anaconda                  custom                   py37_1  
anaconda-client           1.7.2                    py37_0  
anaconda-navigator        1.9.7                    py37_0  
anaconda-project          0.8.4                      py_0  
appnope                   0.1.0                    py37_0  
appscript                 1.1.0            py37h1de35cc_0  
asn1crypto                1.2.0                    py37_0  
astroid                   2.3.3                    py37_0  
astropy                   3.2.3            py37h1de35cc_0  
atomicwrites              1.3.0                    py37_1  
attrs                     19.3.0                     py_0  
babel                     2.7.0                      py_0  
backcall                  0.1.0                    py37_0  
backports                 1.0                        py_2  
backports.functools_lru_cache 1.5                        py_2  
backports.os              0.1.1                    py37_0  
backports.shutil_get_terminal_size 1.0.0                    py37_2  
backports.tempfile        1.0                        py_1  
backports.weakref         1.0.post1                  py_1  
beautifulsoup4            4.8.1                    py37_0  
bitarray                  1.1.0            py37h1de35cc_0  
bkcharts                  0.2                      py37_0  
blas                      1.0                         mkl  
bleach                    3.1.0                    py37_0  
blosc                     1.16.3               hd9629dc_0  
bokeh                     1.4.0                    py37_0  
boto                      2.49.0                   py37_0  
bottleneck                1.2.1            py37h1d22016_1  
bzip2                     1.0.8                h1de35cc_0  
ca-certificates           2019.10.16                    0  
certifi                   2019.9.11                py37_0  
cffi                      1.13.2           py37hb5b8e2f_0  
chardet                   3.0.4                 py37_1003  
click                     7.0                      py37_0  
cloudpickle               1.2.2                      py_0  
clyent                    1.2.2                    py37_1  
colorama                  0.4.1                    py37_0  
conda                     4.7.12                   py37_0  
conda-build               3.18.11                  py37_0  
conda-env                 2.6.0                         1  
conda-package-handling    1.6.0            py37h1de35cc_0  
conda-verify              3.4.2                      py_1  
contextlib2               0.6.0.post1                py_0  
cryptography              2.8              py37ha12b0ac_0  
curl                      7.65.3               ha441bb4_0  
cycler                    0.10.0                   py37_0  
cython                    0.29.13          py37h0a44026_0  
cytoolz                   0.10.1           py37h1de35cc_0  
dask                      2.8.0                      py_1  
dask-core                 2.8.0                      py_0  
dbus                      1.13.12              h90a0687_0  
decorator                 4.4.1                      py_0  
defusedxml                0.6.0                      py_0  
distributed               2.8.0                      py_1  
docutils                  0.15.2                   py37_0  
entrypoints               0.3                      py37_0  
et_xmlfile                1.0.1                    py37_0  
expat                     2.2.6                h0a44026_0  
fastcache                 1.1.0            py37h1de35cc_0  
filelock                  3.0.12                     py_0  
flask                     1.1.1                      py_0  
freetype                  2.9.1                hb4e5f40_0  
fsspec                    0.6.0                      py_0  
future                    0.18.2                   py37_0  
get_terminal_size         1.0.0                h7520d66_0  
gettext                   0.19.8.1             h15daf44_3  
gevent                    1.4.0            py37h1de35cc_0  
glib                      2.63.1               hd977a24_0  
glob2                     0.7                        py_0  
gmp                       6.1.2                hb37e062_1  
gmpy2                     2.0.8            py37h6ef4df4_2  
greenlet                  0.4.15           py37h1de35cc_0  
h5py                      2.9.0            py37h3134771_0  
hdf5                      1.10.4               hfa1e0ec_0  
heapdict                  1.0.1                      py_0  
html5lib                  1.0.1                    py37_0  
icu                       58.2                 h4b95b61_1  
idna                      2.8                      py37_0  
imageio                   2.6.1                    py37_0  
imagesize                 1.1.0                    py37_0  
importlib_metadata        0.23                     py37_0  
intel-openmp              2019.4                      233  
ipykernel                 5.1.3            py37h39e3cac_0  
ipython                   7.9.0            py37h39e3cac_0  
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                    py37_0  
ipywidgets                7.5.1                      py_0  
isort                     4.3.21                   py37_0  
itsdangerous              1.1.0                    py37_0  
jbig                      2.1                  h4d881f8_0  
jdcal                     1.4.1                      py_0  
jedi                      0.15.1                   py37_0  
jinja2                    2.10.3                     py_0  
joblib                    0.14.0                     py_0  
jpeg                      9b                   he5867d9_2  
json5                     0.8.5                      py_0  
jsonschema                3.1.1                    py37_0  
jupyter                   1.0.0                    py37_7  
jupyter_client            5.3.4                    py37_0  
jupyter_console           6.0.0                    py37_0  
jupyter_core              4.6.1                    py37_0  
jupyterlab                1.1.4              pyhf63ae98_0  
jupyterlab_server         1.0.6                      py_0  
keyring                   18.0.0                   py37_0  
kiwisolver                1.1.0            py37h0a44026_0  
krb5                      1.16.1               hddcf347_7  
lazy-object-proxy         1.4.3            py37h1de35cc_0  
libarchive                3.3.3                h786848e_5  
libcurl                   7.65.3               h051b688_0  
libcxx                    4.0.1                hcfea43d_1  
libcxxabi                 4.0.1                hcfea43d_1  
libedit                   3.1.20181209         hb402a30_0  
libffi                    3.2.1                h475c297_4  
libgfortran               3.0.1                h93005f0_2  
libiconv                  1.15                 hdd342a3_7  
liblief                   0.9.0                h2a1bed3_2  
libpng                    1.6.37               ha441bb4_0  
libsodium                 1.0.16               h3efe00b_0  
libssh2                   1.8.2                ha12b0ac_0  
libtiff                   4.1.0                hcb84e12_0  
libxml2                   2.9.9                hf6e021a_1  
libxslt                   1.1.33               h33a18ac_0  
llvm-openmp               4.0.1                hcfea43d_1  
llvmlite                  0.30.0           py37h98b8051_0  
locket                    0.2.0                    py37_1  
lxml                      4.4.1            py37hef8c89e_0  
lz4-c                     1.8.1.2              h1de35cc_0  
lzo                       2.10                 h362108e_2  
markupsafe                1.1.1            py37h1de35cc_0  
matplotlib                3.1.1            py37h54f8f79_0  
mccabe                    0.6.1                    py37_1  
mistune                   0.8.4            py37h1de35cc_0  
mkl                       2019.4                      233  
mkl-service               2.3.0            py37hfbe908c_0  
mkl_fft                   1.0.15           py37h5e564d8_0  
mkl_random                1.1.0            py37ha771720_0  
mock                      3.0.5                    py37_0  
more-itertools            7.2.0                    py37_0  
mpc                       1.1.0                h6ef4df4_1  
mpfr                      4.0.1                h3018a27_3  
mpmath                    1.1.0                    py37_0  
msgpack-python            0.6.1            py37h04f5b5a_1  
multipledispatch          0.6.0                    py37_0  
navigator-updater         0.2.1                    py37_0  
nbconvert                 5.6.1                    py37_0  
nbformat                  4.4.0                    py37_0  
ncurses                   6.1                  h0a44026_1  
networkx                  2.4                        py_0  
nltk                      3.4.5                    py37_0  
nose                      1.3.7                    py37_2  
notebook                  6.0.2                    py37_0  
numba                     0.46.0           py37h6440ff4_0  
numexpr                   2.7.0            py37h7413580_0  
numpy                     1.17.3           py37h4174a10_0  
numpy-base                1.17.3           py37h6575580_0  
numpydoc                  0.9.1                      py_0  
olefile                   0.46                     py37_0  
openpyxl                  3.0.1                      py_0  
openssl                   1.1.1d               h1de35cc_3  
packaging                 19.2                       py_0  
pandas                    0.25.3           py37h0a44026_0  
pandoc                    2.2.3.2                       0  
pandocfilters             1.4.2                    py37_1  
parso                     0.5.1                      py_0  
partd                     1.0.0                      py_0  
path.py                   12.0.2                     py_0  
pathlib2                  2.3.5                    py37_0  
patsy                     0.5.1                    py37_0  
pcre                      8.43                 h0a44026_0  
pep8                      1.7.1                    py37_0  
pexpect                   4.7.0                    py37_0  
pickleshare               0.7.5                    py37_0  
pillow                    6.2.1            py37hb68e598_0  
pip                       19.3.1                   py37_0  
pkginfo                   1.5.0.1                  py37_0  
pluggy                    0.13.0                   py37_0  
ply                       3.11                     py37_0  
prometheus_client         0.7.1                      py_0  
prompt_toolkit            2.0.10                     py_0  
psutil                    5.6.5            py37h1de35cc_0  
ptyprocess                0.6.0                    py37_0  
py                        1.8.0                    py37_0  
py-lief                   0.9.0            py37h1413db1_2  
pycodestyle               2.5.0                    py37_0  
pycosat                   0.6.3            py37h1de35cc_0  
pycparser                 2.19                     py37_0  
pycrypto                  2.6.1            py37h1de35cc_9  
pycurl                    7.43.0.3         py37ha12b0ac_0  
pyflakes                  2.1.1                    py37_0  
pygments                  2.4.2                      py_0  
pylint                    2.4.4                    py37_0  
pyodbc                    4.0.27           py37h0a44026_0  
pyopenssl                 19.0.0                   py37_0  
pyparsing                 2.4.5                      py_0  
pyqt                      5.9.2            py37h655552a_2  
pyrsistent                0.15.5           py37h1de35cc_0  
pysocks                   1.7.1                    py37_0  
pytables                  3.6.1            py37h5bccee9_0  
pytest                    5.2.4                    py37_1  
pytest-arraydiff          0.3              py37h39e3cac_0  
pytest-astropy            0.5.0                    py37_0  
pytest-doctestplus        0.4.0                      py_0  
pytest-openfiles          0.4.0                      py_0  
pytest-remotedata         0.3.2                    py37_0  
python                    3.7.5                h359304d_0  
python-dateutil           2.8.1                      py_0  
python-libarchive-c       2.8                     py37_13  
python.app                2                        py37_9  
pytz                      2019.3                     py_0  
pywavelets                1.0.3            py37h1d22016_1  
pyyaml                    5.1.2            py37h1de35cc_0  
pyzmq                     18.1.0           py37h0a44026_0  
qt                        5.9.7                h468cd18_1  
qtawesome                 0.6.0                      py_0  
qtconsole                 4.5.5                      py_0  
qtpy                      1.9.0                      py_0  
readline                  7.0                  h1de35cc_5  
requests                  2.22.0                   py37_0  
ripgrep                   0.10.0               hc07d326_0  
rope                      0.14.0                     py_0  
ruamel_yaml               0.15.46          py37h1de35cc_0  
scikit-image              0.15.0           py37h0a44026_0  
scikit-learn              0.21.3           py37h27c97d8_0  
scipy                     1.3.1            py37h1410ff5_0  
seaborn                   0.9.0              pyh91ea838_1  
send2trash                1.5.0                    py37_0  
setuptools                41.6.0                   py37_0  
simplegeneric             0.8.1                    py37_2  
singledispatch            3.4.0.3                  py37_0  
sip                       4.19.8           py37h0a44026_0  
six                       1.13.0                   py37_0  
snappy                    1.1.7                he62c110_3  
snowballstemmer           2.0.0                      py_0  
sortedcollections         1.1.2                    py37_0  
sortedcontainers          2.1.0                    py37_0  
soupsieve                 1.9.4                    py37_0  
sphinx                    2.2.1                      py_0  
sphinxcontrib             1.0                      py37_1  
sphinxcontrib-applehelp   1.0.1                      py_0  
sphinxcontrib-devhelp     1.0.1                      py_0  
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp    1.0.2                      py_0  
sphinxcontrib-jsmath      1.0.1                      py_0  
sphinxcontrib-qthelp      1.0.2                      py_0  
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml 1.1.3                      py_0  
sphinxcontrib-websupport  1.1.2                      py_0  
spyder                    3.3.6                    py37_0  
spyder-kernels            0.5.2                    py37_0  
sqlalchemy                1.3.11           py37h1de35cc_0  
sqlite                    3.30.1               ha441bb4_0  
statsmodels               0.10.1           py37h1d22016_0  
sympy                     1.4                      py37_0  
tbb                       2019.8               h04f5b5a_0  
tblib                     1.5.0                      py_0  
terminado                 0.8.2                    py37_0  
testpath                  0.4.4                      py_0  
tk                        8.6.8                ha441bb4_0  
toolz                     0.10.0                     py_0  
tornado                   6.0.3            py37h1de35cc_0  
tqdm                      4.38.0                     py_0  
traitlets                 4.3.3                    py37_0  
unicodecsv                0.14.1                   py37_0  
unixodbc                  2.3.7                h1de35cc_0  
urllib3                   1.24.2                   py37_0  
wcwidth                   0.1.7                    py37_0  
webencodings              0.5.1                    py37_1  
werkzeug                  0.16.0                     py_0  
wheel                     0.33.6                   py37_0  
widgetsnbextension        3.5.1                    py37_0  
wrapt                     1.11.2           py37h1de35cc_0  
wurlitzer                 1.0.3                    py37_0  
xlrd                      1.2.0                    py37_0  
xlsxwriter                1.2.6                      py_0  
xlwings                   0.16.0                   py37_0  
xlwt                      1.3.0                    py37_0  
xz                        5.2.4                h1de35cc_4  
yaml                      0.1.7                hc338f04_2  
zeromq                    4.3.1                h0a44026_3  
zict                      1.0.0                      py_0  
zipp                      0.6.0                      py_0  
zlib                      1.2.11               h1de35cc_3  
zstd                      1.3.7                h5bba6e5_0
```

Comment: Maybe a Mac-specific effect. I tried the code on an Android phone (Pydroid app, Python 3.7.2) with ARM architecture and & needs somewhat less than factor 10 more time than > for all iteration counts. In combination with Lakshmi's results I would conclude that it is specific to the OS or maybe your machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy to perform such operations faster:

```
import numpy as np
import time

x = 1.0
y = 2.0

xxx = np.array([
    [True, False, True],
    [True, False, False]
    ])


iterations_list = np.array([1e3, 1e4, 1e5], dtype=int)
for iterations in iterations_list:
    print('=========')

    t0 = time.time()
    z = list()
    for _ in range(int(iterations)):
        z.append(x if x > y else y)

    t1 = time.time()

    total = t1-t0
    print('>','iterations:', iterations, 'time:', total)


    t0 = time.time()
    zzz = list()
    for _ in range(int(iterations)):
        zzz.append(np.bitwise_and(xxx[0,:],xxx[1,:]))
    t1 = time.time()

    total = t1-t0
    print('&','iterations:', iterations, 'time:', total)

    print('=========')
```

[image]

Comment: I have ran the code you have provided on a 2013 MacBook air OSX macOS Catalina 10.15.1 on Python version 3.7.5 on NumPy Version 1.17.3 and I am unable to get the same results as you. With the NumPy np.bitwise_and I get even slower results.

=========
> iterations: 1000 time: 0.003387928009033203
& iterations: 1000 time: 0.48714303970336914
=========
=========
> iterations: 10000 time: 0.002219676971435547
& iterations: 10000 time: 0.024232149124145508
=========
=========
> iterations: 100000 time: 0.020628929138183594
& iterations: 100000 time: 131.95177507400513
=========

Comment: I have edited my question and have provided the results from the "conda list" commands.

Comment: I tried out on windows machine.One difference in the conda list  result i could found is we are using python from intel channel